# Changing folder/project icons in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to change folders and project icons in the Solution Explorer of Visual Studio 2010 ? Example, C# projects have that little C# icon, that is the one that I would like to change -

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it uses normal registry file associations.  The HKCR\VisualStudio.cs.10\DefaultIcon key value is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\csproj.dll,1  The 2nd icon in the file with size 16x16 is indeed the icon I see in in the Solution Explorer window.

Backup the key value and change it to your own icon.  Restart VS.